# Node JS Controller - invoking a function that has a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

My controller is a soap client as shown below

```
    var _ = require('lodash'),
    memoize = require('memoize'),
    soap = require('soap'),
    http = require('http');
    var wsdlUrl = 'http://www.proxixnetwork.com/gsert/PxPointGeocode.asmx?WSDL';

    var geocode = function(req,res){
      var sessionId = null;
      soap.createClient(wsdlUrl, function(err,client){
          var args = {"username":'user123', "password":'password123'};
          client.PxPointGeocode.PxPointGeocodeSoap.Authenticate(args,function(err,result){
          res.jsonp(result.AuthenticateResult.SessionID);
        })

      });

    }

    exports.authenticate = geocode;
```

This soap service provides a session id that will be used in subsequent requests. Hence, I wanted to use 'memoize' to cache the method.

I defined a method that wraps around the soap call and 'memoize'ing it but the problem is that the call to soapClient is not happening.

I do not know how to make the call from router wait for the soap call
Note: Also tried async library's waterfall but did not work.

```
    var _ = require('lodash'),
      memoize = require('memoize'),
      soap = require('soap'),
      http = require('http'),
      wsdlUrl = 'http://www.proxixnetwork.com/gsert/PxPointGeocode.asmx?WSDL';

    var getSession = function () {

      var args = {"username": 'user123', "password": 'password123'};
      var sessionId = null;
      soap.createClient(wsdlUrl, function (err, client) {
        console.log('Inside proxix client'); //not printing
        client.PxPointGeocode.PxPointGeocodeSoap.Authenticate(args, function (err, result) {
          sessionId= result.AuthenticateResult.SessionID; 
        //if I use res.jsonp() - the call could be made 
        })

      });
    return sessionId;
    };

    var cached = memoize(getSession);

    var geocode = function (req, res) {
      var sesssionObj = cached();
      res.jsonp(sessionObj);

    }
    exports.authenticate = geocode;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two issues I'm seeing are :

1. memoize is a caching mechanism but is in no way going to change the ansynchronous nature of your function.  Returning sessionId will not work because it is not set before it gets to that line.  You need to use a callback.
2. You have not specified which arguments you want memoize to use for the caching, nor where you are getting those values.  I'm going to assume for this example that it's username, password and wsdlUrl. and that they are set directly in req.

.

```
var _ = require('lodash'),
memoize = require('memoize'),
soap = require('soap'),
http = require('http');

var getSessionId = function(username,password,wsdlUrl,callback){
    soap.createClient(wsdlUrl, function(err,client){
        var args = {"username":username, "password":password};
        client.PxPointGeocode.PxPointGeocodeSoap.Authenticate(args,function(err,result){
            if(err){
                return callback(err);
            }
            callback(null,result.AuthenticateResult.SessionID);
        })
    });
});

var getSessionIdCached = memoize(getSessionId,{async:true});

var geocode = function(req,res){
    getSessionIdCached(req.username,req.password,req.wsdlUrl,function(err,sessionId){
        if(err){
            //do some error handling, and probably return
        }
        res.jsonp(sessionId);
    });
});

exports.authenticate = geocode;
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly that is my requirement. Your code helped correct my mistake. was struggling to pass the 'res' in the final callback. Thanks again.